# Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"

Tags: pdftex, miktex, fontspec, texstudio

Good evening to everyone,

I'm facing a problem while attempting to write my CV on TexStudio.
I was used to write it following this template:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}
%add external pdf pages
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\begin{center} % just for vertical spacing and killing indent
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.072]{photo.jpg}&\Huge Hugo \textsc{}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & UK  | 31 April 1978 \\
%    \textsc{Address:}   & UK \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & UK \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & \\
    \textsc{email:}     & \\
%    \textsc{Tax code:}  & \\
%    \textsc{Skype:}  & \\
    \textsc{LinkedIn:}  & \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{English:}&Mothertongue\\
\textsc{Spanish:}&Intermediate Knowledge\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Communicative and Organizational Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item ------------.
    \item -----------------.
    \item ----------.
\end{itemize}

 \section{Computer Skills}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    Advanced knowledge:& Microsoft Windows OSs, Unix-like OSs, OpenOffice.org package, \\& Microsoft Office package (Excel, Word, PowerPoint)\\

\end{tabular}

\section{Interests and Activities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Traveling,
    \item  Go-karting, 
\end{itemize}

\vspace{25pt}

\textit{I authorize the handling of personal information}

\vspace{32pt}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \hspace{30pt} , 27/04/2016  &  \hspace{150pt}\textit{}\\ & \hspace{120pt} \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{firm.png}\\
\end{tabular}


\newpage
\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds}{Master of Science in \textsc{Engineering}}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}}&\textsc{Grade}&\textsc{Credit Hrs}\\ \hline
INSTRUMENTATION LABORATORY  & 26&   6\\


        & Total&120\\\cline{2-3}
&\textsc{Gpa}&\textbf{26.7}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip


\end{document}
```

Actually I'm not able anymore to compile and view the pdf of my CV since it appears the error "cannot-use-pdftex".

In the past days I had to format my PC and re-install everything, including Miktex and TexStudio: however I have already installed all the packages required to compile the tex file.

Before formatting I didn't not have these sort of problems and I always compiled using PdfLatex

Any advice would be precious since I'm a noob on latex.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: You have to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` if used with `.otf` fonts and `fontspec`

Comment: As Christian says, `fontspec` and `pdflatex` are incompatible.

Comment: Ok got it but when I try to compile with xelatex this error comes out: `File 'xetex.def' not found. ...d{ver@\Gin@driver}\input{\Gin@driver}}{}`

Comment: Don't load packages multiple times, especially with different options. `hyperref` should be loaded last with very few exceptions (e.g. `cleveref` must come after). You don't need `color`. Try `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` rather than loading `graphicx` without options twice.

Comment: There was a reorganisation of the graphics drivers this month, and you should install the `graphics-def` package. TTake the opportunity to update your MiKTeX. Also, needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor`. And, as a general rule,  load `hyperref` as the last package (very few exceptions).

Comment: Firtsly both Christian and Steven were right since i was remembering wrong about what method I was using to compile. Then, as Bernard suggested, I've installed manually 'graphics-def' and synchronized Miktek packages. Finally, I've been able to compile using XeLatex. Thanks!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and remove the calls of `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. You need *no* option to `graphicx` (cfr is wrong in suggesting the `dvipdfmx` option). Don't `\RequirePackage`: `\usepackage` is the right command.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in the comments.